# Converting the scalar function to table values function to return a boolean value

Tags: sql-server

I have written a scalar function to return warning message . I need to convert the function to table valued function to return a boolean value as well as warning message.
Could somebody tell me how do I go about it

```
ALTER FUNCTION [declaration].[GetAgreementStatusMessage](@AcceptanceWindowExpiry datetime)  
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)   
AS   

BEGIN  
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInDays INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInHours INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifference INT;
    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(1000);

    -- This function returns a message based on the number of days left for the agreement to expire 
    SELECT @timeDifferenceInDays = DATEDIFF(d,  GETUTCDATE(), @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  
    IF @timeDifferenceInDays > 1
      BEGIN
            SELECT @result = 'You have remaining ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @timeDifferenceInDays) + ' days to accept this agreement. Not accepting the terms of this agreement will revoke your access to Genistar Online.'
       END
    ELSE 
     BEGIN
        SELECT @timeDifferenceInHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,  GETUTCDATE(),  @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  
          IF @timeDifferenceInHours >= 0 AND @timeDifferenceInHours <= 24
             BEGIN 
                SELECT @result = 'You have reached the end of the agreement review period to scrutinise and accept or decline the outstanding agreements. The acceptance of the outstanding agreements can no longer be deferred and must be affirmed now to continue using Genistar Online.'
             END
          ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT @result = 'Expired'
          END
        END
        RETURN @result;  
    END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change your return type to a table variable, and then fill that table variable within your code

```
CREATE FUNCTION [GetAgreementStatusMessage](@AcceptanceWindowExpiry datetime)  
RETURNS @result TABLE (InPeriod bit, Message varchar(1000))
AS   

BEGIN  
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInDays INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInHours INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifference INT;

    -- This function returns a message based on the number of days left for the agreement to expire 
    SELECT @timeDifferenceInDays = DATEDIFF(d,  GETUTCDATE(), @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  
    IF @timeDifferenceInDays > 1
      BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @result (InPeriod, Message)
                   VALUES (1, 'You have remaining ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @timeDifferenceInDays) + ' days to accept this agreement. Not accepting the terms of this agreement will revoke your access to Genistar Online.')
       END
    ELSE 
     BEGIN
        SELECT @timeDifferenceInHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,  GETUTCDATE(),  @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  
          IF @timeDifferenceInHours >= 0 AND @timeDifferenceInHours <= 24
             BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO @result (InPeriod, Message)
                       VALUES (0, 'You have reached the end of the agreement review period to scrutinise and accept or decline the outstanding agreements. The acceptance of the outstanding agreements can no longer be deferred and must be affirmed now to continue using Genistar Online.')
             END
          ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @result (InPeriod, Message)
                       VALUES (0, 'Expired')
          END
        END
      RETURN;  
END;
```

Comment: I am getting error must declare table variable @result

Comment: Yes, a comma, and you also needed to remove the original declaration of @result, so only remains the new one (a table variable). I have updated the code, please try again.